# case update trigger change case ownership

Tags: apex, trigger, case, ownership

my customer service people are using LiveHelpNow and after chat window closes I've the agent name from Live help now mapped to case.Case_Owner__c custom text field. I'm writing a trigger that will update the Default case Owner(user lookup standard field) based on searching the User object and matching with the text value in the Case.Case_Owener__c custom field. and here is the code, but I believe the last part is giving SOQL query error of Limit issue 50001.

```
trigger livehelp on Case (before insert, before update) {
set<Id> cas = new set<Id>();
set<String> ownername = new set<String>();
for(case c:Trigger.new)
{
    cas.add(c.Id);
    ownername.add(c.Case_owner__c);
}

List<user> allUsers = [SELECT ID, name From User Where name =:ownername];
map<string,Id> userIds = new map<string, Id>();
for(user userIdStore: allUsers)
{
    userIds.put(userIdStore.Name, userIdStore.Id);
}
list<case> cases = [select Id, Case_owner__c from case];
for(case ca : cases)
{
    if(userIds.containsKey(ca.Case_owner__c))
    {
        ca.OwnerId = userIds.get(ca.Case_Owner__c);
    }
    else
    {
        ca.OwnerId = null;
    }
}
update cases;
```

}

Comment: Why are you getting every single case at `list<case> cases = [select Id, Case_owner__c from case];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has a number of problems.

## Null Owner

You can't set OwnerId to null. Don't even try.

## Unlimited Queries

You're querying every case in the system. This won't scale well, as you've observed.

## Alternate Assignment

If you set up an assignment rule, it will take priority over your trigger.

## Null Case Id

Before insert, there won't be a case Id. Similarly, you can't query for the records in Trigger.new in a "before insert" trigger because they do not yet exist in the database.

## Infinite Recursion

Using an update as you've done would result in an infinite loop. However, since you're using "before insert/before update", you don't need to do another DML, because records in Trigger.new that are modified will result in the changes being saved to the database.

---

That said, I see what you're trying to do, so assuming you don't have an assignment rule, your code might look like:

```
Map<String, Id> ownerUser = new Map<String, Id>();
for(Case record: Trigger.new) {
    ownerUser.put(record.Case_Owner__c, null);
}
for(User record: [SELECT Name FROM User WHERE Name IN :ownerUser.keySet()]) {
    ownerUser.put(record.Name, record.Id);
}
for(Case record: Trigger.new) {
    if(ownerUser.get(record.Case_Owner__c) != null) {
        record.OwnerId = ownerUser.get(record.Case_Owner__c);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1st thanks for all your help. 2nd the case is not being created and no error. 3rd if I try to change the before insert to after insert or after update I get  "Error:Apex trigger LiveHelpCaseOwner caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: LiveHelpCaseOwner: System.LimitException: Too many query rows: 50001"

Comment: @sfdfox it is working now, it was due to other triggers interfering with this one. Thanks for your contribution.